# I didn't get "On The Road" Hat

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

I asked a question on Stack Overflow 1 hour ago using Android app.
But I didn't get the "On The Road" hat.
Criteria for getting that hat is:

> ask a question through the iOS or Android app

Then why I didn't get that hat ? ;( I need my hat...

Answer (score 9):

The hat has an [implicit quality requirement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245123). The question needs to have a score greater than zero in order to qualify for the hat.